# STM32, Keil and *** error 65: access violation at 0x60000000 : no 'write' permission

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, keil

I tried to run LCD software in Keil for STM32, but I got

```
*** error 65: access violation at 0x60000000 : no 'write' permission
```

Do you know how to solve that error ?
I saw that I can create a MAP, but it didn't work

```
MAP  0x00000000, 0x70000000  READ WRITE  // allow R/W access to IO space
```

[image: Click for full resolution]

(Click for full resolution image)

from this definition :

```
#define LCD_REG              (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60000000)) /* RS = 0 */
#define LCD_RAM              (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60020000)) /* RS = 1 */
```

Thanks for reading

I'm using simulator
[image]

Comment: i followed this video to resolve the same issue related to access violation when i try to use keil in simulator mode https://youtu.be/gEedJNB2WfM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to:

```
Project -> Options for Target '<your target>' -> Debug tab
```

and select the debugger option.
[image]

Comment: then what should I do ? I don't have ULINK, can't I use simulator ?

Comment: I was under impression that you wanted to run the code on a microcontroller, in which case you would choose an appropriate debugger from the list (not necessarily a ulink). I have not tried using a simulator yet, so won't be able to help with that, sorry.

Comment: I'm not using ULink as my debugger, I'm using simulator

Comment: So I need to have ULink or Jlink and the board..?

Comment: @RickAnt - you should not accept an answer that does not solve your problem.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer??

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the simulator:

- select the simulator in project properties on the debug page
- start a debugging session. Don't run the code yet
- go to Debug -> Memory Map... and manually map the ranges the simulator cannot find.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, this is not a forum.  Your answer is better suited as a comment as it doesn't aim to solve the given question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DanielGrillo - actually, this is an attempted answer to the specific part of the poster's question which concerned their inability to enact a map.  Doing so may or may not solve the problem, but this is an entirely appropriate response to the question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Have you seen it before Dmitry's edition? Now is much better to understand but at that time I couldn't.

Comment: The information content was the same.  Both before and after the edit, the answer is targeted at someone knee-deep in the problem, not an uninvolved reader.

Comment: @DanielGrillo Yeah, I could only understand it because I had Keil at hand and could match the labels in the dialog with several words used in the answer. I really hope the author will learn from these comments and improve their wording next time.

Answer (score -1):

Translated to English using Google translate - RM:

To eliminate the "error 65: access violation at 0x60000000 : no 'write' permission" error, a map.ini file was created indicating the available memory areas according to the Memory map for this chip.

I used stm32f030k6.

The contents of the map.ini file:

MAP 0x40000000, 0x40008000 READ WRITE // allow R/W access

MAP 0x40010000, 0x40018000 READ WRITE // allow R/W access

MAP 0x40020000, 0x400243FF READ WRITE // allow R/W access

MAP 0x48000000, 0x480017FF READ WRITE // allow R/W access

The map.ini file is placed in the folder with the project file.

To connect it go here:

Project -> Options for Target 'Target 1'... ->Debug -> Initialization File

Comment: Thanks for your post. This site requires English-only answers.  I translated your post using Google translate. Please post future material in English.